# Checking syntax of a string or file

Tags: raku

Is there any internal (as in memory-only) equivalent to running raku -c on a file to check the syntax?
So far, there are two methods

- Running EVAL, but this actually runs the code. It's fast, but might cause some memory problems if evaluated structures are not garbage-collected
- Creating a temporal file and running perl6 -c over it, but as said above, this is safe but an order of magnitude slower.

I am looking for a safe (as in perl6 -c) and fast (as in EVAL) alternative. Any idea?

Comment: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/d41f162da0 adds a `:compile-only` flag to `EVAL`.  Not sure yet if jnthn will allow it in, so it may very well be reverted.

Comment: Looks like the feature is in, with a small rename: `:check`: see https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/5b3a8ce0ed

Comment: Hi JJ. Just doing some tidying up of SO. If `:check` or similar has landed and does what you want, iwbni if you (or Liz) added a minimal answer ("See `:check` comment above" would be more than enough imo) and the answer was accepted. If it didn't, then iwbni you edited your answer to leave a record of how it didn't measure up. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in the comments above, Raku now supports this by letting you pass the `:check` named parameter to [EVALFILE](https://docs.raku.org/routine/EVALFILE) (to check the syntax of a file) or to [EVAL](https://docs.raku.org/routine/EVAL) (to check the syntax of a string).  In either case, the function will return `Nil` if the syntax is valid and will throw the relevant exception if it is not.